# Sitecore Installation Assistant 9.3 path denied installing Solr

Tags: solr, sitecore-install-assistant

When trying to install Sitecore 9.3 using the new Sitecore Install Assistant, SOLR fails to install with the following error:

```
[------------------------ DownloadSolr : DownloadFile ------------------------]
[DownloadSolr]:[Download] http://archive.apache.org/dist/lucene/solr/8.1.1/solr-8.1.1.zip => C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Temp\solr.zip

[-------------------------- UnpackSolr : ExpandArchive -----------------------]

[---------------------------- MoveSolr : MoveItem ----------------------------]
Access to the path 'C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Temp\solr-8.1.1\contrib' is denied.
```

I'm running the installer as an admin but that seems to make no difference.

Comment: Can you try specifying the Install Path to some other drive other than C drive?

Answer (score 3):

Try specifying the value of the **Install Path** to some other drive other than C drive in the **Install Solr** step while running the Sitecore Installation Assistant.

Some paths in C Drive may cause permission issues unless you have granted access in the folder's properties in file explorer.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Looking at `Solr-SingleDeveloper.json`. There is a parameter named `TempLocation`:

```
"TempLocation": {
        "Type": "String",
        "Description": "Alternative location to save downloads. If left on the default $Env:Temp will be used.",
        "DefaultValue": "SIF-Default",
        "Validate": "[TestPath(variable('Temp.Location'))]"
    }
```

If you open a PowerShell console and type `$Env:Temp` I'm sure you'll see the same path you listed in your question.

This parameter begins in `XP0-SingleDeveloper.json` named `PackagesTempLocation`. You should be able to add a new parameter in `XP0-SingleDeveloper.ps1` to target this:

#### XP0-SingleDeveloper.ps1

```
# Install XP0 via combined partials file.
$singleDeveloperParams = @{
  Path = "$SCInstallRoot\XP0-SingleDeveloper.json"
  SqlServer = $SqlServer
  ...
  AllowedCorsOrigins = $AllowedCorsOrigins
  SitePhysicalRoot = $SitePhysicalRoot
  PackagesTempLocation = "C:\Your\New\Location"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same issue.
Please run the same Sitecore setup after deleting these 2 folders - `C:\Users\[yourusername]\AppData\Local\Temp\solr-8.1.1` and `C:\Solr`.

Note :- `Folder-"AppData"` is hidden by default in Windows File Explorer.

Thanks,
Kalpesh

Answer (score 0):

[image: access to path denied]

I had to change the `templocation` like jrap suggested but I did it on `D drive` because I tried like in the image below on `C drive` and still I had the same issue.
After creating the same folder on `D drive` also gave permission to the folder from the `Security tab` as `full control` for the user I logged on to the machine and `Everyone` it worked.