# Error in Solr installation on Sitecore 10 SIA

Tags: solr, sitecore-install-assistant

I am getting below error in Solr installation using SIA. Access denied on copying solr files to installation directory from Temp folder. I am using admin access. Please advise.
[image]

Error Logs:

```
[------------------------ TestSolrPath : WriteInformation --------------------]
Solr install path is available.

[--------------------- TestSolrService : WriteInformation --------------------]
Solr service name is available.

[------------------------ TestSolrPort : WriteInformation --------------------]
Solr port is available.

[---------- ThrowIfTestsFail [Skipped] : WriteError --------------------------]

[-------------------- CreateSolrFolder : EnsurePath --------------------------]
[CreateSolrFolder]:[Create] C:\Users\spa7982\OneDrive\Solr\sc11solr-8.4.0

[------------------------ DownloadSolr : DownloadFile ------------------------]
[DownloadSolr]:[Download] http://archive.apache.org/dist/lucene/solr/8.4.0/solr-8.4.0.zip => C:\Users\spa7982\AppData\Local\Temp\solr.zip

[-------------------------- UnpackSolr : ExpandArchive -----------------------]

[---------------------------- MoveSolr : MoveItem ----------------------------]
Access to the path 'C:\Users\spa\AppData\Local\Temp\solr-8.4.0\licenses' is denied.
[TIME] 00:00:45
Access to the path 'C:\Users\spa\AppData\Local\Temp\solr-8.4.0\licenses' is denied.
```

Comment: It's a permission issue try this - https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/25566/sitecore-installation-assistant-9-3-path-denied-installing-solr

Comment: Can you try providing Solr Install Path to another drive rather than C?

Comment: Error messages need to be text, not images. SEO.

Comment: @SumitHelaiya I have tried that link . Not able to change temp path where solr gets downloaded and extracted .

Comment: @SumitBhatia I am not installing solr in C. I am using different drive. Issue is here while copying the solr files from temp to installation folder temp folder path is not accessible.

Comment: @Sushil Pal While it's not a solution but a workaround, try to install Solr (or whole Sitecore) with Sifon https://sifon.uk/.

Comment: @SushilPal can you update your question with logs? can the log file in SIA folder

Comment: Have you started SIA as administrator? Does the user have access to that folder `C:\Users\spa\AppData\Local\Temp\solr-8.4.0\licenses`?